# Jade lang in a regular web app without node

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-applications, angularjs, pug

Is it possible to use Jade in a regular web app without running on Node js? The question may sound crazy as Jade engine is written in node but wanted to find out if it  can can be used oustide of Node.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, it all depends what you really want.
You can compile a function to jade directly, through the CLI :
`jade -w index.jade` (`-w` is "watch for change", auto-recompiles)

or, if you use another language, you may be interested in other implementations :

- [PHP](https://github.com/everzet/jade.php) (I think you may find forks maintained)
- [Scala](http://scalate.fusesource.org/versions/snapshot/documentation/scaml-reference.html)
- [Ruby](https://github.com/slim-template/slim)
- [Python](https://github.com/SyrusAkbary/pyjade)
- [Java](https://github.com/neuland/jade4j)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just need to somehow get the jade compiler to run at the right time. You could accomplish that manually though a [watcher script](https://gist.github.com/dweldon/4644690) or with a build environment like [nodefront](http://karthikv.github.io/nodefront/).

Comment: Thank you! So looks like I can use it with Java Quartz as a post-compilation step.